# Python: memory efficient list with list.sort(cmp=myfnc)

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, large-data

What is the best way to improve this code:

```
def my_func(x, y):
    ... do smth ...
    return cmp(x',y') 

my_list = range(0, N)
my_list.sort(cmp=my_func)
```

A python's list takes a lot of memory in comparison with numpy array (6800MB vs 700MB),
but nympy.array doesn't have the sort function with cmp argument.

Are there other ways to improve memory usage or sort numpy's array with my cmp function?

**Update:** my current solution is a C function (shared with SWIG) that sorts a huge array of integers and returns it to python after sorting.

But I hope that there is some way to implement memory efficient sorting of huge datasets with Python. Any ideas?

Comment: `cmp` is deprecated. You should either use `key` or decorate - sort - undecorate. Maybe if you fill in your `cmp` function someone could show you how to do it one of those ways.

Comment: `cmp` is only deprecated in Python 3. And there is [functools.cmp_to_key](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) to automatically convert the function in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

If you can write a ufunc that convert your array, you can do fast sort by argsort:

```
b = convert(a)
idx = np.argsort(b)
sort_a = a[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use the builtin `sorted` with an numpy array:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10, 1, -1)
>>> sorted(a, cmp=lambda a,b: cmp(a,b))
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

It is not in-place, so you have 1400 MB compared to 6800 MB.

Comment: the sorted part takes anyway 6800 MB, I think it converts numpy to list

Comment: If you look at the documentation for `sorted` (`help(sorted)`), it says the result is always a list.